# Python Generate a dynamic dictionary from the list of keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I do have a list as given below -

```
keyList1 = ["Person", "Male", "Boy", "Student", "id_123", "Name"]
value1 = "Roger"
```

How can I generate dynamic dictionary which can be retrieved as below -

```
mydict["Person"]["Male"]["Boy"]["Student"]["id_123"]["Name"] = value
```

The list could be anything; Variable Length or consisting of "N" number of elements unknown to me...

Now  I do have another list, so that My dictionary should be updated accordingly

```
keyList2 = ["Person", "Male", "Boy", "Student", "id_123", "Age"]
value2 = 25
```

i.e. If Keys "Person", "Male", "Boy", "Student", "id_123" already exists, the new key "age" should be appended ...

Comment: I would suggest to append all items in the list and use the resultant string as key. It would be lot easier.

Comment: The answers to this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384174/more-pythonic-way-of-counting-things-in-a-heavily-nested-defaultdict

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm just learning python, so my code could be not very pythonic, but here's my code

```
d = {}

keyList1 = ["Person", "Male", "Boy", "Student", "id_123", "Name"]
keyList2 = ["Person", "Male", "Boy", "Student", "id_123", "Age"]
value1 = "Roger"
value2 = 3

def insert(cur, list, value):
    if len(list) == 1:
        cur[list[0]] = value
        return
    if not cur.has_key(list[0]):
        cur[list[0]] = {}
    insert(cur[list[0]], list[1:], value)

insert(d, keyList1, value1)
insert(d, keyList2, value2)

{'Person': {'Male': {'Boy': {'Student': {'id_123': {'Age': 3, 'Name': 'Roger'}}}}}}
```

Comment: This ends up being pretty similar to my solution. One simple suggestion: avoid `.has_key` whenever possible; prefer the quicker and more understandable `if list[0] not in cur`.

Comment: thanks, I agree that it's more readable and readability counts, but why it's quicker?

Comment: Try it using `timeit`. On my computer, `in` is twice as fast as `.has_key` (0.0672µs vs. 0.117µs). `.has_key` is a method lookup, whereas `in` is a builtin which is dispatched much quicker.

Comment: `.has_key` is deprecated and doesn't exist in Python3

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by making nested `defaultdict`s:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def recursive_defaultdict():
    return defaultdict(recursive_defaultdict)

def setpath(d, p, k):
    if len(p) == 1:
        d[p[0]] = k
    else:
        setpath(d[p[0]], p[1:], k)

mydict = recursive_defaultdict()

setpath(mydict, ["Person", "Male", "Boy", "Student", "id_123", "Name"], 'Roger')

print mydict["Person"]["Male"]["Boy"]["Student"]["id_123"]["Name"]
# prints 'Roger'
```

This has the nice advantage of being able to write

```
mydict['a']['b'] = 4
```

without necessarily having to use the `setpath` helper.

You can do it without recursive `defaultdict`s too:

```
def setpath(d, p, k):
    if len(p) == 1:
        d[p[0]] = k
    else:
        setpath(d.setdefault(p[0], {}), p[1:], k)
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could subclass dict:

```
class ChainDict(dict):
    def set_key_chain(self, keyList, value):
        t = self
        for k in keyList[:-1]:
            t = t.setdefault(k, {})
        t.setdefault(keyList[-1], value)

c = ChainDict()
c.set_key_chain(['Person', 'Male', 'Boy', 'Student', 'id_123', 'Name'], 'Roger')
print c
>>{'Person': {'Male': {'Boy': {'Student': {'id_123': {'Name': 'Roger'}}}}}}

c.set_key_chain(['Person', 'Male', 'Boy', 'Student', 'id_123', 'Age'], 25)
print c
>>{'Person': {'Male': {'Boy': {'Student': {'id_123': {'Age': 25,
      'Name': 'Roger'}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your own class derived from dict where the **init** method takes a list and a single value as inputs and iterate through the list setting the keys to value, define an update method that takes a list and a new value and for each item that is not already a key set it to the new value, (assuming that is what you need).

Forget the idea of

> > > mydict["Person"]["Male"]["Boy"]["Student"]["id_123"]["Name"] = value1`

as it is confusing with subindexes.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to dealing with similar stuff, so I can suggest some guidelines, but again I am naive in Python, so this is just a guideline...

you have a list of keys
, so you can definitely start with a loop iterating for each value and then assign the value

like

```
for i in keylist:
if type(keylist[i]) == dict:
        do something
    else:
        keylist[i] = {}
```

in the do something, you need to increment i and change index to [i][i+1] and then follow the same untill i+n = len(keylist)

Answer (score 0):

Use `tuple(keyList1)` as key. (tuples are immutable and therefore can be dict keys).

You will have a world of headache with the nested dict approach. (nested loops for enumeration, legacy data when the hierarchy needs to change, etc.).

On a second thought, maybe you should define a person class

```
class Person(object):
    gender = "Male"
    group = "Student"
    id = 123
    Name = "John Doe"
```

then use a list of all persons and filter with e.g.

```
male_students = [s for s in  ALL_PERSONS where s.gender=="Male" and s.group="Student"]
```

... for <= 10000 students you should be fine performancewise.

Answer (score -2):

```
>>> mydict = {}
>>> keyList1 = ["Person", "Male", "Boy", "Student", "id_123", "Name"]
>>> value1 = "Roger"
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x.setdefault(y, {}), keyList1, mydict)
{}
>>> mydict["Person"]["Male"]["Boy"]["Student"]["id_123"]["Name"] = value1
```

You can also do it in one step like this

```
>>> keyList2 = ["Person", "Male", "Boy", "Student", "id_123", "Age"]
>>> value2 = 25
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x.setdefault(y,{}), keyList2[:-1], mydict).update({keyList2[-1]: value2})
```

Comment: >>> mydict
{'Person': {'Male': {'Boy': {'Student': {'id_123': {'Name': 'Roger'}}}}}}

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni, er.. where does `reduce(lambda x, y: x.setdefault(y, {}), keyList1, mydict)` depend on the number of elements or the specific keys?